# Error while using SSIS Failed to decrypt protected XML node "DTS:Password"

Tags: sql-server, encryption, ssis

1. I am running an SSIS package from a .bat file on a windows server
2. The package is being run through the Windows Task Scheduler
3. I created the task using my own admin level login and the process has been package has been running without an issue
4. The team I am on had a "service account" created where the password will never expire to use to run the Task
5. I opened the task and when I hit OK I saved the task using the service account and password.  I have verified that I am using the correct password and tested saving with an incorrect password, which fails.
6. The only change made to the task is under security options where, instead of my account it is using the service account (which is NOT an admin account)
7. No changes were made in SSIS.
8. The last error is a SQL connection error
9. If I revert back to having the task run under my admin account everything works.

I know this error has been reported in other threads, but the situation seems to be different.    Any help you can give me would be appreciated.

Windows Task Scheduler Screenshot:
[image: Windows Task Scheduler Screenshot]

Errors:

> Started:  4:27:49 PM
>   Error: 2016-02-25 16:27:53.26
>     Code: 0xC0016016
>     Source: Load_DIM_DATE
>     Description: Failed to decrypt protected XML node "DTS:Password" with error 0x8009000B "Key not valid for use in specified state.". You may not be authorized to access this information. This error occurs when there is a cryptographic error. Verify that the correct key is available.
>   End Error
>
> Error: 2016-02-25 16:27:53.54
>     Code: 0xC0016016
>     Source: Load_DIM_DATE
>     Description: Failed to decrypt protected XML node "DTS:Password" with error 0x8009000B "Key not valid for use in specified state.". You may not be authorized to access this information. This error occurs when there is a cryptographic error. Verify that the correct key is available.
>   End Error
>
> Error: 2016-02-25 16:27:56.73
>     Code: 0xC0202009
>     Source: Load_DIM_DATE Connection manager "Res Frcst"
>     Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E4D. An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80040E4D  Description: "Login failed for user 'xxxxxxx'.".
>   End Error

Comment: No the situation is not different at all. I'm guessing you have protection level _EncryptAllWithUserKey_ (or _EncryptSensitiveWithuserKey_) right? There are many blogs and articles explaining about how protection levels work. Good on you for posting the error but you also need to post the protection level so we don't have to make assumptions.